# relation in model with more than one table

Tags: yii, model, relation

i have 
three tables

**posts**

- id

- title

**postrelations**

- post_id

- category_id

**categories**

- id

- title

table posts linked with categories through postrelations. i need to set relation in posts to get in view title of category. How to set such relation?

Comment: have you generated models of these tables?

Comment: yes. of course i created them

Comment: then please post the relations(auto generated by yii) of all 3 models separately.

Comment: sorry, i was wrong. i have a myisam db. i didnt generated table relations. now in model posts i have relations `            'postrelations '=>array(self::HAS_MANY,'Postrelations',array('post_id'=>'id')),
            'categories'=>array(self::HAS_MANY,'Categories',array('category_id'=>'id'),'through'=>'postrelations'),`

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are several problems here:
1) As you defined the models you have a many to many relation. Yii does not know to generate many to many relations as it only looks at 1 level of relations. So your relations can be improved.
Instead of defining the relation how you defined it, you should to for posts a single relation that looks like

```
'categories' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'categories', 'postrelations(category_id, post_id)', 'order'=>'.... ASC'),
```

You actually have an exact Many to Many relation so you should have no problem accessing the relation with $post->categories. Almost the exact same way you can define a relation for the categories model, just change some fields around.

2) there is no single category title, your post can belong to multiple categories (if it should belong to only one then your tables are wrong). If you want to get the name of all the categories you can either to a

```
foreach($post->categories as $category) { ... }
```

Or (this is untested but it should work) to get the name of the categories separated with a coma, you can do a

```
echo implode(",", CHtml::listData($post->categories, 'id', 'title')));
```